# How to sort x-axis names by sorting y-axis in R without ggplot2?

Tags: r, sorting

Say this is my data:

```
Alpha    Number
  a       5
  b       2
  c       7
  d       1
  e       9
  f       3
  g       4

barplot(sort(Number,decreasing = TRUE))
```

When I add x-axis values using `axis(1,at = c$b, labels = c$b)`, as expected, it just shows in alphabetical order as mentioned in the table. Instead, what I need is to add x-axis according to the sorted values in y-axis without using ggplot2.

I tried `barplot(Number[order(Number,decreasing = TRUE),]` too but it did not work.

Since "Alpha" column are not numbers, `Number~Alpha` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. But is this what you are looking for: `barplot(sort(d$Number,decreasing = TRUE),names.arg=d$Alpha[order(d$Number,decreasing=T)])`?

Comment: @Lamia Wow! Yes. This is what I was looking for.It worked. Sorry for my English.
name.arg did not result anything in help section. What is this? Thank you.

Comment: If you do `?barplot`, you will see that `names.arg` is an argument to define the labels below each bar.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `axis` here, you can specify the labels within the `barplot` function:

```
barplot(sort(d$Number,decreasing = TRUE),names.arg=d$Alpha[order(d$Number,decreasing=T)])
```